# Java user input from class

Tags: java

i'm curious why isn't this working? every time the class gets called it output right away both enter user and enter pass and doesn't let me enter them one by one. I just want the code to take the user input one by one getting called from a class or whatever suggestion you might have.

thanks

output

Enter 1

1
Enter user:

Enter pass: 
a

```
public void takeinfo() {

    String a,b;
    System.out.println("Enter user: ");
    a=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter pass: ");
    b=input.nextLine();

}


public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

    int choice;
     choice=input.nextInt();
      if(choice==1) {
         order.takeinfo();
         order.login();
      }
     else if(choice==2){
       order.register();
      }
   exit();
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to be the full Code. What does the input Object look like ? is it a Scanner instance ?

Comment: you write them both in one method, of course they are going to be executed after each other. What did you expect?

Comment: Your code should be reproducible. If people can't compile your code, they won't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the answer you want?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe I dind't explain myself very well but you understood my question. A new Scanner as you suggested was what I  needed inside the class. Thanks